# sql to aggregate duplicate and append additional data at the end

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data stored in a table like the format below. Heading1,heading2 and so on are the columns name. As you can see I have repetitive data a b c d and then two different values.
I want to query this so as I can get output as mention in second.
For ex - first four rows are same in heading1,2,3,4 so output must be
a b c d 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 5, I mean i just grouped all the duplicate data and added the different data in one row. Is this possible?

Origin Data

```
heading1 | heading2 | heading3 | heading4 | heading5 | heading6         
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
a | b | c | d | 1 | 1 |         
a | b | c | d | 2 | 2 |         
a | b | c | d | 3 | 4 |         
a | b | c | d | 4 | 5 |         
a | b | d | c | 5 | 5 |
```

Output needed

```
heading1 | heading2 | heading3 | heading4 | heading5 | heading6 | | |   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
a | b | c | d | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3| 4 |  5 

a | b | d | c | 5 | 5 |
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you on? Your result shows 2 rows with different number of columns. A query result is a (virtual) table - its rows always have the same number and type of columns for each row.

Comment: Are you using 2005 or 2008 -- windowing functions might be helpful here.

Comment: I am using sql server 2008. if data can be aggregated I can add headings.

Comment: @RolandBouman rows 1 to 4 from original data are joined together to get row 1 in output.row 2 in output is as it is since it has no matching/duplicate data rows following it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](http://blog.shlomoid.com/2008/11/emulating-mysqls-groupconcat-function.html) post:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
(
    heading1 NVARCHAR(1)
    , heading2 NVARCHAR(1)
    , heading3 NVARCHAR(1)
    , heading4 NVARCHAR(1)
    , heading5 NVARCHAR(1)
    , heading6 NVARCHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE
          SELECT 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '1', '1'
UNION ALL SELECT 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '2', '2'
UNION ALL SELECT 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '3', '4'
UNION ALL SELECT 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '4', '5'
UNION ALL SELECT 'a', 'b', 'd', 'c', '5', '5'

DECLARE @CONCAT VARCHAR(500)

SELECT heading1, heading2, heading3, heading4
    , cols5and6
FROM @TABLE a
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT heading5 + ' | ' + heading6 + ' | '
    FROM @TABLE b
    WHERE a.heading1 = b.heading1
        AND a.heading2 = b.heading2
        AND a.heading3 = b.heading3
        AND a.heading4 = b.heading4
    FOR XML PATH('')
) d (cols5and6)
GROUP BY heading1, heading2, heading3, heading4, cols5and6
```

Output:

```
heading1    heading2    heading3    heading4    cols5and6
a   b   c   d   1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 
a   b   d   c   5 | 5 |
```

Comment: I want the value that is coming in cols5and6 to be in separate columns not in one column. is that possible?

Comment: Of course, just select them separately instead of selecting them together with a string concat.